# Two similar computeres on same network, different traceroutes (one slow - one fast)

Tags: network

My SO's computer has a very slow internet connection. So I compared her traceroute to xkcd.com with mine.

We are on the same network, on both on os-x. It's a simple 4g home router.

`tracerouter --version`shows for both computers: `Version 1.4a12+Darwin`

Whats going on. Is this normal - or should I fear that her computer in one way or the other has been infected with something?

Thanks in adance

---

**HER Traceroute:**

```
homerouter.cpe (192.168.1.1)  39.330 ms  3.035 ms  1.317 ms
 2  * * *
 3  10.66.65.9 (10.66.65.9)  62.314 ms  14.781 ms  16.639 ms
 4  172.18.82.5 (172.18.82.5)  20.875 ms
    172.18.82.77 (172.18.82.77)  17.990 ms
    172.18.82.1 (172.18.82.1)  27.821 ms
 5  172.18.102.18 (172.18.102.18)  66.594 ms
    172.18.102.22 (172.18.102.22)  39.764 ms
    172.18.102.10 (172.18.102.10)  27.536 ms
 6  172.18.112.69 (172.18.112.69)  342.240 ms
    172.18.112.26 (172.18.112.26)  19.643 ms
    172.18.112.10 (172.18.112.10)  19.123 ms
 7  10.66.239.1 (10.66.239.1)  174.269 ms  16.297 ms  17.411 ms
 8  10.66.190.1 (10.66.190.1)  37.279 ms
    10.66.190.5 (10.66.190.5)  67.059 ms
    10.66.190.1 (10.66.190.1)  64.153 ms
 9  10.66.190.9 (10.66.190.9)  23.476 ms
    80.251.201.34 (80.251.201.34)  44.302 ms
    10.66.190.9 (10.66.190.9)  30.610 ms
10  te0-7-0-9.ccr22.sto03.atlas.cogentco.com (149.11.76.89)  34.041 ms  32.451 ms  31.745 ms
11  be2282.ccr42.ham01.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.72.105)  33.515 ms  36.725 ms  36.022 ms
12  be2187.ccr42.ams03.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.74.125)  45.993 ms  40.564 ms  49.224 ms
13  be2488.ccr42.lon13.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.39.110)  123.664 ms  127.274 ms
    be2266.ccr42.par01.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.61.197)  145.043 ms
14  be2278.ccr42.par01.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.62.77)  137.534 ms
    be2491.ccr22.lpl01.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.39.117)  124.006 ms
    be2489.ccr42.lon13.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.39.113)  133.644 ms
15  be2491.ccr22.lpl01.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.39.117)  127.980 ms
    be2325.ccr21.jfk04.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.47.30)  153.184 ms
    be2177.ccr22.dca01.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.41.206)  150.222 ms
16  be2151.ccr42.jfk02.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.40.74)  179.934 ms
    be2490.ccr42.jfk02.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.42.85)  131.913 ms
    be2151.ccr42.jfk02.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.40.74)  130.256 ms
17  be2325.ccr21.jfk04.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.47.30)  128.718 ms
    border3.pc1-bbnet1.ext1.nym.pnap.net (216.52.95.21)  385.322 ms
    be2096.ccr42.jfk02.atlas.cogentco.com (154.54.30.41)  132.597 ms
18  border4.pc2-bbnet2.ext1.nym.pnap.net (216.52.95.77)  141.949 ms
    38.88.194.86 (38.88.194.86)  171.578 ms *
19  border3.pc2-bbnet2.ext1.nym.pnap.net (216.52.95.76)  176.381 ms 164.233 ms
    border3.pc1-bbnet1.ext1.nym.pnap.net (216.52.95.21)  140.472 ms
20  border3.pc1-bbnet1.ext1.nym.pnap.net (216.52.95.21)  134.944 ms
    border4.pc1-bbnet1.ext1.nym.pnap.net (216.52.95.22)  183.385 ms
    inapvoxcust-1662.border4.ext1.nym.pnap.net (63.251.26.42) 178.056 ms
21  107.6.106.82 (107.6.106.82)  122.202 ms
    inapvoxcust-1661.ext1.nym.net (63.251.26.30)  157.541 ms
    inapvoxcust-1662.border4.ext1.nym.pnap.net (63.251.26.42) 142.759 ms
```

**My traceroute**

```
traceroute to xkcd.com (107.6.106.82), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  10.117.1.1 (10.117.1.1)  84.001 ms  82.721 ms  85.223 ms
 2  5.157.38.17 (5.157.38.17)  83.975 ms  81.686 ms  81.190 ms
 3  5.153.234.245 (5.153.234.245)  89.978 ms  81.102 ms  75.212 ms
 4  ae3-210.rt.tc1.sto.se.retn.net (87.245.249.12)  86.517 ms  105.302 ms  77.556 ms
 5  ae0-8.rt.tlx.nyc.us.retn.net (87.245.233.114)  302.024 ms  201.309 ms  201.645 ms
 6  nyiix1.voxel.net (198.32.160.128)  206.396 ms  200.610 ms  198.535 ms
 7  0.ae59.tsr1.lga5.us.voxel.net (208.122.44.202)  203.763 ms  201.836 ms  315.534 ms
 8  0.te2-1.tsr1.lga11.us.voxel.net (173.231.161.146)  308.101 ms  249.612 ms  203.591 ms
 9  107.6.106.82 (107.6.106.82)  200.770 ms  201.065 ms  203.104 ms
```

**EDIT**
Today my network shows both homerouter.cpe and the cogento.com network. And her internet isn't slow anymore.

SO I am baffled - but can't seem to reproduce yesterdays situation.

Comment: I think this is a network question rather than a security question, but it's a *really interesting* network question.  I am curious why we don't see `homerouter.cpe` in your traceroute, but do in hers.

Comment: Is this network you're both on a fairly simple one with a single gateway (see my question above) or does it have multiple paths to the Internet.  What are the default gateway settings for both computers?  Are you in the United States? (Best if you edit the answers into your question instead of answering in comments.)

Comment: My route out to xkcd includes a couple of the same hops as *hers*.  I think it's weird that it cogentco.com hops as well as taking over 100ms for each one.

Comment: My guess I'd that you are using different protocols for tracerouting.

Comment: Thanks for the help @BobBrown et.al. I couldn't a stackexchange network site. So posted here. For now it seems I can't reproduce the situation.